# How to choose tenses in this situation?

Tags: tenses

> Yesterday, I went to a restaurant, drinking some beer with a friend whom I had not seen for several years. I found that he had changed very much. He was lean, now he was very fat...(self-made)

I feel strongly unhappy about these sentences. Yes, I met him in the past. But his change is a fact when I telling the story. I am confused about the usage of the tenses.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest these changes:

Yesterday I went to a restaurant, *and drank* some beer with a friend who I had not seen for several years. I found that he had changed very much. He was lean, *and had become* very fat...(self-made)

I hope this helps!

Comment: ***whom*** I had; he ***used to be*** lean

Comment: and now he **is** fat

Comment: but had now become very fat

Answer (score 1):

I think only two changes are necessary: "he *had been* lean, and *now was* fat", contrasting the pluperfect with the past tense to indicate that he was lean before he was fat.

The gerundive (drinking) is not tense-specific, so is fine as it is. If you wished you could also write "I found him much changed" to iron out the repetition of the pluperfect, but this would merely be a matter of taste.